# google account getting logged out after closing window

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, google

I am new to Linux, and i installed chrome signed in with google account, but when i close browser i am getting **logged out**, but not with other accounts like ***ask Ubuntu*** accounts are not getting logged out.
Its only happening with google accounts.
this issue is with firefox, chrome and brave browser

Comment: Most likely due to to your option to "delete cookies" when you close your browser and did not add a exception for google website.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed that issue with the below steps.

open Chrome then click on triple dot on top right  >  **Settings** > **Privacy and security** > **Site Settings** > **Additional Content settings** > **On device site data** > then finally select "**Allow sites to save data on your device**"

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely because you chose the option in your browsers to "Delete cookies" when you close your browser. In that same section of options, You also need to add a exception for Google so you will not get logged out when you close your browser. It appears you have already done this for other accounts like **askubuntu**.